# Understanding 2 apparently similar functions

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `powerOne` and `powerTwo` in mathematical/programming terms? Especially `return base * powerOne(base, exponent - 1);`? What are the consequences if one is chosen above the other?

```js
function powerOne(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return base * powerOne(base, exponent - 1);
  }
}
console.log(powerOne(2, 3));

function powerTwo(base, exponent) {
  if (exponent == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return base ** exponent
  }
}

console.log(powerTwo(4, 2));
```

Comment: "*What is the difference between powerOne and powerTwo in mathematical/programming terms?*" The first one is recursive, the second one isn't.

Comment: "*What are the consequences if one is chosen above the other?*" you probably shouldn't be choosing either of these. If you need a function `Math.pow()` exists. Or you can use the `**` operator. These functions are not needed.

Comment: The second function body can be just `return base ** exponent`, which highlights what VLAZ wrote. Also, the first function can only handle positive integer exponents.